# SSIS Package not executing even after reaching in execution mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis

I have created SSIS package in VS 2010. What actually happens is When I execute the package it goes in execution mode, but nothing happens. Even the validation doesn't start. When you go for Execution results to check the progress, It will show all the progress of last run.

Earlier, When i was facing the same issue, I save the package and build it again. After that it runs successfully. But now, after doing the same, I cant execute my package.

Can anyone tell me why am I facing this issue?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with vs.  Could you run a repair on it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Is there any other solution for this?